# Switch Statement Survey

Tags: java

I am having a few problems with this build. First it is not all it will not load the main class. Second I need the user to input their choice of music and then I need the compiler to print selection. Can someone help me with this code? Please excuse me but I am totally new to programming.

```
public class music {

public static void music(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("What's your favorite kind music?: ");
    System.out.println("1. Country");
    System.out.println("2. Rock");
    System.out.println("3. Heavy Metal");
    System.out.println("4. Folk");

    try{
    BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int s = Integer.parseInt(bufferRead.readLine());
        switch(s){
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Country");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Rock");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Heavy Metal");
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Folk");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Country");
                break;
      }



}catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What happens? Do you get an error? Stacktrace? How ate you running it?

Comment: I am compiling it with JCreator LE and it says "--------------------Configuration: music - JDK version 1.7.0_07 <Default> - <Default>--------------------
Error: Could not find or load main class music

Process completed"

Comment: Ok I tried the "public static void main(String[] args) {" and it is still giving me a will not load main class music.

Comment: @user1743771 Have you saved this class in `music.java` file? Since your class `music` is public class containing `main` method, your `compilation unit` must have the same name as the `class name`. Save it as `music.java`.

Comment: For the record, the code in this question is a literal copy-paste from the answer to OP's previous question. Well, not entirely literal---OP introduced a bug that folks are fixing now in this question.

Comment: It is saved as music.java. Still showing same error

Comment: Problem is fixed. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

The problem with the source as posted is that you do not have an [entry point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) to your class (i.e. a method called `main`).

**Suggestions**

Since you mentioned you are also new to programming, I've taken the liberty to include some stylistic suggestions to make your code simpler and easier to read (IMO):

```
import static java.lang.System.in;
import static java.lang.System.out;

import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Music {

    private static final String DEFAULT_MUSIC = "Country";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, String> musicOptions = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
        musicOptions.put(1, DEFAULT_MUSIC);
        musicOptions.put(2, "Rock");
        musicOptions.put(3, "Heavy Metal");
        musicOptions.put(4, "Folk");

        out.println("What's your favorite kind music?: ");
        for (Entry<Integer, String> option : musicOptions.entrySet()) {
            Integer choice = option.getKey();
            String music = option.getValue();

            out.printf("%d. %s\n", choice, music);
        }

        final int choice = new Scanner(in).nextInt();
        String music = musicOptions.get(choice);
        if (music == null) {
            music = DEFAULT_MUSIC;
        }

        out.println(music);
    }

}
```

**Further Reading**

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html
[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

Comment: Ok I put in your final int and I was able to build but it came up with the error "cannot find symbol" location line 10

Comment: I compiled and tested this, are you sure you copied it correctly? Did you copy the static imports at the top?

Comment: I missed a line. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Boo for deeply nested ternaries.

Comment: I personally believe in this case this is most terse and readable. Perhaps you can clarify with a more scientific statement why this merits a "Boo". Thanks

Comment: Ternaries should be reserved for concise, un-nested usage, which this isn't. Any change to the body renders the construct useless. There's zero reason to use it, and every reason to refactor the functionality into a method-*particularly* since the OP is a beginner. Also, if you don't use an @, the person you're replying to may not be alerted you've replied.

Comment: @DaveNewton I don't know what you mean by "Any change to the body renders the construct useless". I don't see "zero reason", since it's easier to read, IMO (as mentioned)

Comment: Add a logging statement. Add additional functionality. Do anything. You can believe what you want; imo this is an abuse of the construct, does nothing to aid comprehension or communication, and is an inappropriate replacement for the obvious refactor.

Comment: @DaveNewton I totally agree about the need to refactor (which I just did). However, it has nothing to do with the control structure, and everything to do with being DRY. I think your arguments are more based on preference. Although that is perfectly fine, lets try to avoid implying they are definitive.

Comment: It's not preference to keep code flexible, it's common sense. Again-believe whatever you want, but imo this is abusive and makes even the smallest modification a structure-wide change, which is unnecessary, and a poor example for a beginner.

Comment: @DaveNewton From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#.3F:_in_style_guidelines): `Appropriate use of the conditional operator in a variable assignment context reduces the probability of a bug from a faulty assignment as the assigned variable is stated just once as opposed to multiple times.` Furthermore, `When properly formatted, the conditional operator can be used to write simple and coherent case selectors`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17990/discussion-between-btiernay-and-dave-newton)

Comment: Oh, well, if Wikipedia says so... *lol* Get over it--we disagree. Life goes on.

Comment: (I'll reiterate my concerns. Unextensible: if the body changes, you throw away the construct. Deeply nested. Unsuitable for beginners. Nothing in the Wikipedia counters that or makes me believe it's an appropriate use.)

Answer (score 4):

```
public static void music(String[] args)
```

This does not look like main method. You should use `main` in place of `music`: -

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Also, the `compilation` unit containing this class should have the same name as that of the class. And better use your class name as : - `Music` and save it as `Music.java`

Answer (score 3):

Your method must be named `main`. Review [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html#MAIN).

Instead of:

```
public static void music(String[] args) {
```

try:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

`public static void music(String[] args)` defines a static method with the same names as the class.

Answer (score 3):

your code is looks ok but only You can not rename main method, `main()` method signature must be `public static void main(String[] args)` and your code should be like

```
public class Music{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     ...
    }
}
```

*Note* - *main method signature is constant and find the significance below.*

**public** - public everyone can access it.

**static** - Java environment should be able to call this method without creating an instance of the class , so this    method must be declared as static.

**void** - the return void so there's no return value.

**main( )** - the name of the method, main because it's the main method.

**String args[]** - arguments to this method. This method must be given an array of Strings, and the array will be called 'args'.

Comment: You mean `public class Music` ?

Answer (score 1):

function name must be `main()` not music()

```
public class music {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("What's your favorite kind music?: ");
    System.out.println("1. Country");
    System.out.println("2. Rock");
    System.out.println("3. Heavy Metal");
    System.out.println("4. Folk");

    try{
    BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int s = Integer.parseInt(bufferRead.readLine());
        switch(s){
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Country");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Rock");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Heavy Metal");
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Folk");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Country");
                break;
      }



}catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: There is no reason to post the complete code, if the problem is just with the `first` line.